# django fastcgi can't run

Tags: python, django, timeout, fastcgi

I use fastcgi to run a django application. The command I use to run it is as follows:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=3035
```

If I input `ps -ef|grep python` I can see the thread also, but when i use `lynx localhost:3035` to open it, I get a 504 gateway timeout.

So instead, now I use

```
python manage.py runserver 3035
```

and it runs OK. I don't know the reson. In the past, I use django 1.2 and it was OK.

my server info:

> debian5.0, django1.3, python2.6

Answer (score 0):

The FastCGI protocol is different from HTTP protocol. You need to add some layer talking both HTTP and FastCGI protocols, between lynx and devserver. For example nginx w/ FastCGI module configured.

Answer (score 0):

If deploy with nginx, the better choices are gunicorn or uwsgi(supported natively by nginx).

gunicorn:

http://gunicorn.org/run.html

uwsgi

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example